# Access mobile camera using HTML5/ JavaScript with company logo (web browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, camera

The task is, on clicking a button on page, I need to show camera in mobile, with HTML5/JavaScript with a company logo on the camera (stays at fixed position). When a user takes picture, the logo should display on the picture taken.

I found script that access camera but I can't show company logo while camera is open.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

index.html

```
<body>
 <iframe id="camera">Here is the Iframe you see the camera output in.</iframe>
 <img src="A path to the logo" id="logo">
</body>
```

style.css

```
#camera {
 Position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

#logo {
 Position: absolute;
 Right: 5px;
 Bottom: 5px;
 z-index: 2;
}
```